# Fabrica for different parsers

Tags: python, xml, json, oop, csv

Problem:

- Write a class Fabrica what give: way to file and/or format file,
  return: data from this file in dict.
- Write a abstract class Reader what have just one method "reader"
  without implementation.
- Write 3    classes CSVReader, XMLReader,    JSONReader. They
  inherited from Reader,    must implementation method "reader" with
  functionality for parse csv, json, xml. Must return data in
  dict format to fabrica.

So i have next problem. I don`t understand how to correctly write this all classes. I wrote solution, but have error (code below). 
**My question is**: how to correctly write this all classes?

And recommend me a some good book about OOP please)

```
class FactoryRader:
    def __init__(self, fileName,frmt=None):
        self.frmt = frmt
        self.fileName = fileName

    def __str__(self):
        return Reader.openFile(self.fileName, self.frmt)



class Reader:
    def openFile(fileName, frmt):
        try:
            with open(fileName, 'rU') as data:
                if fileName.endswith('.csv') or frmt == 'csv':
                    return CSVReader.reader(data)
                if fileName.endswith('.xml') or frmt == 'xml':
                    return XMLReader()
                if fileName.endswith('.js') or (frmt == 'json' or frmt == 'js'):
                    return JSONReader()
                else:
                    return 'Incorrect File!'
        except IOError:
            print('Cant open')

    def reader(data):
        pass


class CSVReader(Reader):
    def reader(data):
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(data.readline(), [',',';'])
        data.seek(0)
        reader = csv.DictReader(data, dialect=dialect)
        for row in reader:
            print (row)


class JSONReader(Reader):
    def reader(data):
        pass

class XMLReader(Reader):
    def reader(data):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = FactoryRader('CsvExamples/price.csv')
    print(data)
```

Error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ClassParsers.py", line 62, in <module>
    print(data)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Answer (score 0):

These is by no means a complete solution; it's just a bunch of remarks.

As I understand, the try/except block in Reader should go in FactoryReader. There is no such thing as abstract class in Python, so your class Reader could be empty. Or, if you prefer, just

```
class Reader:
    def reader(data):
         pass
```

(if you are using Python2, it's better to use new style classes: `class Reader(object)`).

You are asked for FactoryReader to return a dict, not a string, so the `__str__` function is not important. The Error you get is telling you that the `__str__` method in FactoryReader should return a string. It would be better to not implement `__str__` and use another name for that function; say `get_reader`. And then, you should return the data in a dict way. So it would be

```
def get_reader(self):
    if self.fileName.endswith('.csv') or self.frmt == 'csv':
        return CSVReader(self.filename)
    etc
```

Then,

```
class CSVReader(Reader):
    def reader(filename):
        code to open filename, read it and parse it
        code to convert parsed code into dict
        return dict
```

Similarly for `JSONReader` and `XMLReader`.